# jQuery plugin with multiple methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

I am going to wrap some of my functions in a nice manner and for this I want to go with jQuery approach. Like jQuery having a lots of methods

```
$.parseJson()
$.ajax()
$("div").text("hey my testing");
```

and both methods are present in a same jQuery file. But while reading about how to make a jquery plugin, its specified that you don't need to create multiple functions inside a same plugin. Instead pass an argument which contains the method name as string.

So, Is that the below snippet is correct or do i need to make some corrections in it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.testMethod1 = function () {
            return $(this).each(function () { });
        };
        $.fn.testMethod2 = function () {
            return $(this).each(function () { });
        };
        $.test = function () {
            return "testresult"
        };
    })(jQuery);

    $("div1").testMethod1();
    $("div2").testMethod2();
    $.test();

    //Is that needed to be replace in a different way like
    $("div1").myPlugin("testMethod1");
    $("div1").myPlugin("testMethod2");
    $("div1").myPlugin("test");


</script>
```

Comment: `this` is already a jQuery object. You don't need to re-wrap it.

Comment: Ok, accepted. But is that multiple methods inside a same plugin is correct?

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap does it that way and I think it's more intuitive if all plugins followed the same syntax.

Comment: @Blender - the first way or the second way?

Comment: @Blender But its something like we are calling the plugins through their name. e.g. $("div").myPlugin("externalPlugin1",data) and $("div").myPlugin("externalPlugin2")

Comment: @ManishRawat: Explain your exact situation.

Comment: The exact situation is that, if let say i want to combine multiple plugins in a single jquery file, i have to do it in the approach1 or approach2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second way is preferred because it conserves namespace in the jQuery object.

Read the official jQuery doc for this: [Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Comment: What you mean by conserving namespaces in jQuery. There are already a bunch of pre-defined functions in jQuery so why don't they do it in the same way like       
         
         $("div")("fadeIn")

Comment: It's just the preferred way for most developers. This allows for there to be more plugin possibilities without there being really complex names. It's just the preferable standard.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try using [jquery boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/). It is a good point to start study jQuery plugin development. It's provide a safe and(seem to be) a good solution to create a plugin. They use your second way to call a method.